# Accurate prediction of outlier values

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, xgboost, outliers

I am working on medical data which is related to the calculation of blood pressure(Regression problem). The dataset that I have at the moment is short on numbers for extreme values of systolic and diastolic bp.The Algorithms which I am using at the moment are Neural Networks and XGBoost, both of them who are taking the extreme values as outliers and giving high MAEs on the predictions for the outlier values. Is there a way we can tune the algorithms or the dataset so that the algorithms can give a reasonable prediction on the 'outlier' values? I heard Log-scale transformation of the Dependent variable can be a solution , am I right? are there other ways ?

Thanks in advance
Arjun

Comment: Please don't SHOUT when posting your questions here. It will not get you answers any faster, it makes text harder to read, and frankly it's pretty rude.

Answer (score 0):

Log-scale transformation will make your target distribution look like normal (probably). If so - you are lucky.

If it does not work:

1. Remove outliers from your dataset. They are bringing nothing but noise at this moment. Which harms the model in total.
2. Build one model (regression) on the normal values and another one - on outliers. The last one you can try to simplify: code input values as 0 and 1 (normal values and outliers).
3. Use simpler models (linear: lasso as a start, hubert). Complex models like NN and XGB will finally overfit on your few extreme cases.

Those are common approaches. But, in general, you need to return to EDA and try to analyze these extreme cases: plot distributions, understand dependence between extreme cases of systolic and diastolic bp, same dependence (and correlation) between extreme cases and target variable and so on.